# Unable to load plist into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to load the following plist into an NSArray:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to load the data:

```
// Load the data from the plist file
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
```

However when I place a breakpoint after the data has been loaded I notice that the array is empty. Please can someone help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the filename and path are absolutely correct?

Comment: Not sure if it will make any difference, however the plist is stored in a different folder to the class file that loads it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try loading it into a NSDictionary and asking for the `[ objectForKey:@"Root"]` inside it ?

As far as I remember, property lists are key / value maps and your array is just one of those values.

Answer (score 2):

Your plist file has a dictionary that contains an array. Try this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Root"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```